# Show/Hide features using a filter with mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm working on an indoor project using mapbox and i'm looking for a way to show/hide features (floors) with a specific property `level=x`. In the first version of mapboxjs it was possible to use [this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering-markers/). Now in the GL version I can easily [show/hide a layer using a filter](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/) but this is not what i'm aiming because layers are already defined (rooms, corridors, stairs...) and are not dependant on floors :

```
{
  "id": "rooms",
  "filter": [
    "all", [
      "==",
      "type",
      "room"
    ], [
      "!in",
      "subtype",
      "stairs",
      "elevator"
      ]
  ],
  "source": "indoorSource",
  "source-layer": "indoor",
  ...
},
{
  "id": "handrails",
  "filter": [
    "==",
    "handrail",
    "yes"
  ],
  "source": "indoorSource",
  "source-layer": "indoor",
  ...
}
```

I can query which features I would like to use:

```
map.querySourceFeatures("indoorSource", {sourceLayer: "indoor", filter: ["==", "level", "2"]})
```

but I didn't find a way to show/hide returned features.

For information: indoorSource is a vector tile from a webserver:

```
"indoorSource": {
    "type": "vector",
    "tiles": ["http://xxx.xxx/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"]
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Thibaud

Answer (score 2):

[`Map#setFilter`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map.setFilter) takes filters, just like `Map#querySourceFeatures`, and uses them to show / hide features on the map.

```
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'indoor',
  'source': 'indoor',
  'source-layer': ...
  ...
});

map.setFilter('indoor', ['==', 'level', '2']);
```

Comment: In fact, Map#setFilter will update the filter of a style layer and will remove previous filters. A workaround could be: `map.setFilter("rooms", ["all", map.getFilter("rooms"), ["==", "level", "1"]]);` but this solution is dirty and hard to maintain. Moreover with this solution, I also have to know (and hard-code) all layers which use the tag "level". I've updated my first post for more information about styles I use.

Comment: At this point, you understand the Mapbox API and it is up to you to implement a clean, maintainable architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at indoorequal front-end, based on mapbox to show indoor floors.

Comment: Thanks, finally I did my own implementation few years ago https://github.com/ThibaudM/mapbox-gl-js-indoor

Comment: OK. I don't see any description of what you did about indoor. Could you tell us more ? May I use your job ?